# Prove that: $\prod_{k=1}^n \sin^2(2^kx)\le (3/4)^{n-1}.$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, products

> To prove:$$\prod_{k=1}^n\sin^2(2^kx)\le\left(\frac34\right)^{n-1}.$$

**My approach so far:**

We have:
\begin{align}
\prod_{k=1}^n\sin^2(2^kx)&=\left(\prod_{k=1}^n\sin(2^kx)\right)^2\\\\
&=\left[\Im\left\{\prod_{k=1}^ne^{i\cdot2^kx}\right\}\right]^2\\\\
&=\left[\Im\left\{\exp\left(ix\sum_{k=1}^n 2^k\right)\right\}\right]^2\\\\
&=\left[\Im\Big\{\exp\big(ix(2^{n+1}-2^n)\big)\Big\}\right]^2\\\\
&=\sin^2\left[(2^{n+1}-2^n)x\right].
\end{align}

Now how can I prove that (obviously if I haven't done any mistake so far) :

$\sin^2\left[(2^{n+1}-2^n)x\right]\le\left(\frac34\right)^{n-1}\tag*{}\,?$

---

Please suggest... Thanks in advance.

Comment: This inequality fails for $n=1$ and $x=\frac{\pi}{4}$. In fact, for any $n$ you can choose $x$ to be $\frac{\pi}{2(2^{n+1} -2^n)}$ to make the left expression equal $1$.

Comment: See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3749619

Comment: @Tavish, Yeah! So the conditions should be like $n\in\mathbb N\smallsetminus\{1\}$ and $x\in\mathbb R\wedge x\ne\fracπ{2(2^{n+1}-2^n)}.$

Comment: @Michael Rosenberg, Thank you.